# Plotting with scientific notation in IDL

Tags: plot, idl-programming-language

I would like to know if it is possible ( and how to ) plot numbers in scientific notation (e.g. 4e2  instead of 400) while plotting diagrams with IDL's plot package.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a format for tick values using IDL's standard formatting codes and the [XY]TICKFORMAT keywords. For example, to specify scientific notation for the x axis values, use the following:

```
IDL> plot, findgen(10000), xtickformat='(E7.1)'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. can u also help us the way to print 4x10^2 in IDL plot?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't see the followup question. Check the docs for the XTICKFORMAT keyword. You can set it to be the name of a routine that does custom string formatting instead of a format string. The [docs](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Graphics_Keywords.html#wp332347) have the signature for the routine and an example.